# Font Size resets in NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, nsattributedstring

Am adding an image to a `NSAttributedString` object so I can display them properly in a `UITextView`.
So far, it works great. Only problem is, my Font size is 25 to match my image size but each time I add an image to the `UITextView`, the Font resets to some smaller size. I need to keep the font at 25 to match texts with the image size.

`NSAttributedString` has 3 constructors which take `string`, `attributedString` and `string:attributes:`.

Since I'm not using string, I can't set the attributes using the third constructor and the first 2 won't allow me to set attributes (`UIFont`). I therefore decided to set the Font size from `Interface Builder` and reset it each time I add an image to the `UITextField.

Am facing a problem here because each time I reset the font, the `UITextView` scrolls to the first line (assuming there is so much text, it has scrolled up). How do I set font size after adding image without the `UITextView` scrolling up automatically? Better still, is there a better way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Could you show your code? If I remember well, if you do `[yourTextView setAttributedText:newAttributedString];` it may scroll up automatically, so you have to scroll down (a few questions around the web can be found about it).

Comment: Actually, am not using `textView.setAttributedString()`. Am using `textView.textStorage.insertAttributedString(attributedString: atIndex:)`. Also, am only using that to insert images into the `UITextView`. So, an image, some text then another image etc.

Answer (score -1):

NSMutableAttributed string has some methods you may try, including setting attributes across ranges after the attributed string is constructed.

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy Pope . I tried it but its not exactly working. I'm not sure if its a problem with the range or its just not picking.
This is what I did:
    `let selrange = MessageTxt.selectedTextRange;
     let selstart = selrange?.start;
     let selend = selrange?.end;
     let loc =     MessageTxt.offsetFromPosition(MessageTxt.beginningOfDocument, toPosition: selrange!.start);
        let len = MessageTxt.offsetFromPosition(selstart!, toPosition: selend!);
        let rang = NSMakeRange(loc, len);
        
        mutable.setAttributes(font, range: rang);`